Unable to Add Breakpoint or Debug Using netcoredbg in CLI Mode on Windows
I'm trying to debug a C# project using netcoredbg on Windows, following the instructions in this document.
I've built the CLITestBreakpoint project from the netcoredbg test suite using:
dotnet build -c Debug
Then, I tried to launch the debugger with the following command:
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\workspace\netcoredbg\build\src\Debug\netcoredbg --interpreter=cli -- "dotnet" "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/workspace/netcoredbg/test-suite/CLITestBreakpoint/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/CLITestBreakpoint.dll"
Once in the netcoredbg CLI, I attempted to set a breakpoint at line 9 in Program.cs using:
ncdb> break Program.cs:9
However, I received a warning and error that the breakpoint could not be set:
Breakpoint 1 at Program.cs:9 --pending, warning: No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line.
When I checked the breakpoint status with info break, it showed that the breakpoint was unresolved:
ncdb> info break
    #  Enb  Rslvd  Hits       Source/Function
---------------------------------------------
    1    y  n      0          Program.cs:9

Running the program with run resulted in the following error:
ncdb> run
Error: 0x80004005: E_FAIL
Additionally, when I tried the list command, I received a message indicating that the PDB (Program Database) file couldn't be opened:
ncdb> list
Source code file:
Debug information (PDB file) cannot be opened. Check that PDB file exists and is correct.
ncdb Command execution
File Structure: Here is an image showing my file structure:
Why am I unable to set breakpoints or debug this project using netcoredbg? Is there something wrong with my setup or the way I'm launching netcoredbg?
